# how to make includes() method work with object as a parameter in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

this gives me `false`:

```
var arr = [];
for (y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
  for (x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
    arr.push({y: y, x: x});
  }
}

console.log(arr.includes({y: 1, x: 2}));
```

i tried to slice values of objects in arrays, but it is still `false`:

```
var arr_ = [];
arr.forEach(function(e) {
  arr_.push(Object.values(e));
});

console.log(arr_.includes([1, 2]));
```

in my case i want to filter one array of objects by another:

```
var el = [{y: 1, x: 1}, {y: 1, x: 2}];

var filteredArr = [];
arr.forEach(function(e) {
  if (!el.includes(e)) filteredArr.push(e);
});
```

hope, there is a simple way to make this filter work :)

Comment: you need the same object reference for `includes`. otherwiese each object is different, even with same keys/values.

Comment: @nina-scholz understood, thank you

Answer (score 1):

you can use [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) :

```js
var arr = [];
for (y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
  for (x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
    arr.push({y: y, x: x});
  }
}

var el = [{y: 1, x: 1}, {y: 1, x: 2}];

var filtered = arr.filter(a => 
  el.some(b => a.x === b.x && a.y === b.y)
);

console.log(filtered)
```